# How does Exchange 2010 prevent auto-reply loop?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, auto-reply

E.g., 2 users have auto-reply configured. `User A` sends a message to `User B`. `User B`'s auto-reply gets sent to `User A`'s mailbox. That, in turn, causes an auto-reply to be sent from `User A` and insanity ensues.

How does Exchange 2010 prevent this scenario?

Also, can Exchange 2010 prevent a user's mailbox sending more than one auto-reply to the same user in one day?

**Bonus**: Assuming Exchange prevents this, how do I configure the settings?

Comment: Why would you want to configure it? It works fine. Use your time on problems :)

Comment: I just want to know what options are available. We are migrating from another mail system and administration might want to reproduce the way our current system works.

Comment: @Pauska: do you mean use your time to solve problems or make more? I'm pretty good at both.

Comment: Ah, sysadmin banter. Appreciated by so few.

Comment: +1 for offering a bonus question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Auto replies only get sent once per sender, per activation.  There is no auto-reply loop with Exchange systems. [Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/157961)

Comment: To be clear, they are sent once per Sender.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty, I was trying to find the right term... I'll change it.

Comment: Glad to pitch in.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen. Do you know of any official documentation of this behavior?

Comment: added link for referrence

Comment: Sir is mildly appropriate :)

Comment: @Holo: That comment made me chuckle. :)

Comment: @joeq which one?  The one where he's unsure of my gender, or my response to said gender confusion? :)

Comment: @Holo: Your response to the aforementioned gender question was... as they say... priceless.

Answer (score 7):

the header is `x-auto-response-suppress:all` is sent by default on auto replies.  That in conjunction with `x-ms-exchange-inbox-rules-loop` (which contains the sender email address), should resolve any potential loop conditions.

Comment: So another system could also use this header to prevent an auto reply loop correct?

Comment: not that I am aware of

Comment: Exchange often strips Exchange-specific headers as messages leave the organization, @Beaming, so you need to find out whether this header is stripped.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the one per sender restiction.
In auto reply create a rules and a template and set as reply to all
The sender will receive 2 emails on first contact. Then just one on second contact.